# Loop in ajax(request) only the first result work

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, request

I don't understand why the ajax loop only on the first result and how fix it ?

```
   arrayOfMatches.forEach((matchesOfElement) => {
                var query = {
                    platformId: matchesOfElement.platformId,
                    gameId: matchesOfElement.gameId,
                    champion: matchesOfElement.champion,
                    queue: matchesOfElement.queue,
                    season: matchesOfElement.season,
                    timestamp: matchesOfElement.season,
                    role: matchesOfElement.role,
                    lane: matchesOfElement.lane,
                    summonerName: summoner.name,
                    summonerAccountId: summoner.accountId,
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'matches.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: query,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(response, xhr, statusText) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                });
            });
        }
```

The only value unique is "gameId"

Thank by advance !

Comment: That code will definitely do multiple `ajax` calls (well, most likely -- it's one for each entry in the array, so if the array only has one, it'll only be one), overlapping them. It's not clear why you think it isn't doing that, but it definitely does do that.

Comment: Assuming `arrayOfMatches` is an array, the only reason for having **one log only** is that it just has one element, otherwise you would have multiple (possibly unordered) logs.

Comment: Only the first value is submit in the database.

Comment: First you need to locate the problem. Track the count of XHR's in Network in browser developer tool and track the counts of insertions in DB. If there is a difference - then it's looks like problem in backend. Otherwise it could be trouble with collecting `arrayOfMatches`.

Comment: I found the problem, the code wasn't the problem it was the database